# Inject HTML into React/Next.js Site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have been tasked with improving the UI/UX for an external service that runs on React (Next.js). This company says the only customization they offer is a text editor for JavaScript, and to inject changes there. The problem is, I cannot seem to attach to the virtual dom. This text editor creates a JavaScript file, which is then loaded right below the `<body>` element.

Am I missing something, or is this not possible?

```
const nav = document.getElementsByClassName('userbar-wrapper')[0];
nav.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', 'additional HTML code');
```

I'm getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of undefined`

Comment: The error message you're getting is ultimately saying that there is no element with class name "userbar-wrapper" on the page. Maybe there is another class name you should be looking for?

Comment: The element has three classes: userbar-wrapper, is-alternative-version, fixed. I think the issue is the fact that the site is React and virtual dom, and I'm unable to inject anything. The area I'm provided ultimately becomes a javascript file loaded into the header.

Comment: Where and when exactly is that "custom javascript" called? React probably didn't render anything yet when the script is called.

Comment: It's called right below the ```<body>``` tag. I'm pretty sure this isn't going to work - though this is what their development team advises. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. I went through documentation and don't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add a comment due to low rep, however it looks like you're causing a *side effect*, you therefore want to wrap your code in a [useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook, something like the below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const nav = document.getElementsByClassName('userbar-wrapper')[0];
    nav.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', 'additional HTML code');
}, []);
```

Comment: I agree - if I had access to the code itself, I could accomplish this easily. However, I'm only provided a text field in some afterthought admin panel that creates a Javascript file that's called in the header.

Comment: I see. Apologies, your original comment was difficult to understand. In which case, I honestly wouldn't even contemplate making these requested changes - that's the job of the product owner and even if you could do what you're asking, it's not something you should be doing. Since the product owner likely won't make the changes for you, they should be the ones detailing how you can make the changes you want.